# How to use RiotJS custom tags with Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, riot.js

I have a tag called `invoice.tag` which contains a html code that a want to repeat several times.
And i want to use that tag in a view called `add.blade.php`. And in the end of that view i wrote this to call the invoice tag:

```
@section('bottom')
    <script src="{{asset('components/invoice.tag')}}" type="riot/tag"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            riot.mount('invoice');
        })
    </script> @endsection
```

But it doesn't work.
I think it's because a version conflicts, so, anyone knows the correct syntax to use Laravel with RiotJS?

Answer (score 1):

In your master blade file, e.g. `resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php`, make sure you include the corresponding code to display the `bottom` section in the location on the page you want it:

```
@yield('bottom')
```

Comment: Thanks for respond. But i did that before and still doesn't work :(

Comment: I solved reinstalling de RiotJS and making all from scratch.